# javascript help to solve challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm studying javascript and I came across the challenge below, however I don't know how to solve it.
I would like your opinion to know how to get to the result below according to this declarations.

```
// DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW
let increment1 = new Increment()
let increment2 = Increment()

console.log(increment1 == +increment2) // true
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 1
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 2
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 3
```

I have tried to use Prototype to solve.

Comment: What have you tried so far? May you double check the example code? I don't know if you can make a function that can be used with and without `new`...

Comment: I have already tried to solve using closures and prototype but I still haven't managed to the solution.

Comment: It looks like it needs you to make a custom the `toString` method of the `Increment` object/function.

Comment: *HINT* - check if `this.constructor.name` is something useful. `Increment.prototype.toString` should be a custom function which changes a `this` bound variable.

Answer (score 5):

Some things to observe in the given code:

- The function `Increment` is a constructor, since it can be called with `new`. By consequence we know that the value returned by `new Increment` is not a primitive value (like a number), but an object.
- But it should also be possible to call `Increment` without `new`. This means that `Increment` should not assume that `this` is the created object, but should have a provision to explicitly return a value.
- From the use of the unary `+` we learn that the object can be coerced to a number. So we should provide either a `valueOf` or a `toString` method in our object. In the latter case we should let `toString` return a string that is a valid number representation.
- From the use of the template strings we learn that the object can be coerced to a string, producing "1", "2", ...etc. So now we know we should choose for a `toString` implementation and not `valueOf`.
- From the incremental behavior that we see from the printed template literals, we learn that we need a numerical variable that is within the scope of the `toString` function, but not local to it. It is best practice to define the variable in the scope that is defined by `Increment` and not as a global variable (although that would work too).

Taking all the information together, we get this:

```js
function Increment() {
    let count = 0;
    return {
        toString() { return count++; }
    }
}


// DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW
let increment1 = new Increment()
let increment2 = Increment()

console.log(increment1 == +increment2) // true
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 1
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 2
console.log(`val: ${increment1}`)      // val: 3
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part `console.log(increment1 == +increment2) `?

Comment: That is not my code, but given in the code challenge. `+increment2` applies the unary plus operator on `increment2`, which will call its `valueOf()` method if it exists, or else `toString()`. The `==` operator will return a boolean (true when left and right side are equal -- after potential type conversion), and `console.log` will output that boolean.